# deploying netbeans web application on cloud

Tags: java, netbeans, cloud

I created a java web application in NetBeans.i was looking for a cloud service provider to deploy it.Most of the cloud platforms that i checked do not have any plugin for netbeans as they do for eclipse.

I tried to use the Google App Engine for netbeans 6.9 but that does not work for me.I also managed to deploy my app on jelastic but i am looking for some other options.Are there any other cloud service providers which i can use?

I am using glassfish as a server for my application.

Comment: The cloud service providers probably have documentation on deploying the app without an IDE. You could also just install Eclipse for deployment purposes only.

Comment: Yeah but that is lot of hard work.I was looking for providers with GUI

Comment: A lot of hard work? The GAE docs imply it's *one command*: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp (Generally, any deployment that only involves putting your stuff on a single server can't be considered hard work.)

Comment: That said I'm not sure GAE is the right choice if you're targetting Java EE with Glassfish - I believe it's a more limited environment. (And obviously you're not really using Glassfish, you'll end up using whichever appserver your chosen provider uses.)

Answer (score 0):

While deploying your application on Jelastic did you face any difficulties?
Why are you searching for other options? 
The plugin for NetBeans is still under the development and is going to be supported in Jelastic soon. So, stay tuned for updates.

Comment: Yes i faced several difficulties.I created a trial account there.But it crashed within a day and i get 502 Application Down error